# Unable to save screenshot at desired location

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium+Java, I want to save screenshot, which is taken after test failure, at specific location. In order to achieve that I wrote following code -

```
File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcFile, new File("C:\\verifyTakeScreenshotFailure.png"));
```

but this is resulting into error -

> java.io.IOException: Source
>   'C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\screenshot1720506318428476820.png'
>   exists but is not a directory

I'm using Java 8 and Selenium 3. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyDirectory` is used to copy directories. You are looking for `copyFile`

```
FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("C:\\verifyTakeScreenshotFailure.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\verifyTakeScreenshotFailure.png"));
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as Accepted if it's resolved your issue. So it will help for other users as well. Thanks:)